# Setting Queue Arguments For All Consumers In Mass Transit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a simple Mass Transit setup using RabbitMQ and am taking advantage of IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints to automatically create endpoints for my consumers.

The problem is I also want to set some queue arguments i.e. "x-max-length", "x-overflow" on all these queues. Using ConfigureEndpoints it doesn't seem to copy those arguments across.

I'm using MassTransit 5.5.6. I see that in 7.1.6 I could use IConfigureReceiveEndpoint however I cannot upgrade.

Is this possible or do I need to manually specify each endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade, or you'll need to specify it manually for each endpoint.

Comment: Okay, good to know thanks!